# Found my Job Position Listed on a google ad

Tags: job-change, replacement

I work for a small company with only myself and my senior as the developers. We mainly do web development and we have one other person who does mailers basic html. We create the css templates, I doubt that's considered to be a "Developer" position (The person working on the mailer that is). I work on App's due to client's wanting applications and I'm the only one that works with any kind of mobile frameworks.

I stumbled upon a ad for a "Developer & Designer" from the web side of my job design is a small part of it but a part nonetheless, I have to use photoshop for somethings. The job requirements lines up  with what I do.

Now I'm not sure if this is them trying to find a replacement for me or finding someone to take over the web side of my job.

My question in short is.

Do I worry about this? 
Should I ask about it?
& Finally if it is to help me the salary offered is double mine, should I ask about that then?

For my work context, I always do my work on time , I try my best to always be helpful and friendly. So I see no legitimate bases to remove me.

Comment: So I am guessing that the "Developer/Designer" job is your job position? This question needs some editing. I suggest: remove all the info about the high salary, its not important how you found it. Also add why you think it might be your position and not the same position for an addition to your (or any other)  team?
I do agree with the last statement. It is a little weird that you dont know about them looking for some teammember. But maybe they just dont want you to get your hopes up?

Comment: I agree with the first comment, please take your time and try to re-word your question. Also some additional context information will help, for instance, what type of employer do you work for, are there several teams in the company? Have you received a warning or has your boss talked to you about bad performance?

Comment: Nitpick: `add` - do yo mean an `ad` (advertisement)?

Comment: @TroySteven the question has been updated; hopefully some downvoters will reverse theirs now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are semi-qualified, semi-capable and semi-nice, hiring and training a replacement is a huge waste of money. Not to say that it doesn't happen, but usually there are contributing factors that you should already be aware of. For instance, a toxic management culture (like a nasty power struggle) or if you're screwing up so badly that they'd rather replace you than give you feedback.

It is very likely that a big project is coming up, or that they want more work like yours to be done. This is the type of information that management should be aware of. Just approach your manager, tell him that you noticed the ad and ask him what team/project these people will be working on, and ask after the reasoning for expanding the departement. If you want feedback, don't put him on the spot. Suggest that you two schedule a one-on-one, where he gives you feedback and you two discuss his goals for your team/departement and how you can contribute.

**But, about the way you wrote your post:** You sound very worried. When I feel like that, all I see are my errors and I find it really difficult to assess my performance accurately. Are you falling into the same trap?

Take a step back and reality check yourself. Use pen and paper, make a list - an accurate self-assessment is going to help you improve yourself. It also helps if you ever want to argue for a raise.

Evaluate the quality of your work, the quality of your relationships with your coworkers and manager, the value you bring to the team and the impact of any confrontations you may have had. If you make mistakes, do you put effort into fixing them? Do you invest into personal relationships? Do you have other substantive reasons to assume that they would be replacing you?

**Simply put:** If you were your manager, would you want you on the team?

Comment: This make's alot of sense " When I feel like that, all I see are my errors and I find it really difficult to assess my performance accurately" I guess I am So i'll take your advice and just relax a little and i'm going to ask today thank you!